# Trying GET request (size: 142mb) and receive the error: 'Failed to allocate a 296011104 byte allocation with 25165824 free' bytes

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit, dynamic-memory-allocation

The error :-

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
    Process: com.android.kepr, PID: 11206
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 296011104 byte allocation with 25165824 free bytes and 220MB until OOM, target footprint 330823816, growth limit 536870912
        at java.lang.StringFactory.newStringFromUtf8Bytes(Native Method)
        at java.lang.StringFactory.newStringFromBytes(StringFactory.java:80)
        at java.lang.StringFactory.newStringFromBytes(StringFactory.java:101)
        at okio.Buffer.readString(Buffer.kt:313)
        at okio.Buffer.readString(Buffer.kt:302)
        at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.kt:270)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:517)
```

[Size of API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vc74d.png)

Size of API is 142mb and I have tried every possible thing like cursor allocation of 500mb, etc.
but didn't work.

My question: Is there any possible way to allocate this to it's expected size.

OR

Any alternate solution is appreciated.

My retrofit code:

```kotlin
    if (checkInternetRepository.isNetworkConnected()) {
        try {
            isNotesUnderAssetsData = false

            emit(
                BuildingRoomAssetsViewModel.Action.FetchNotesUnderAssetsDataAPIResponse(
                    buildingRoomAssetsRepository.fetchNotesUnderAssets()
                )
            )

        }


if (state.listAllNotesUnderAssetsTabsData != null) {
    Log.d("listNotesUnderAssets", "" + state.listAllNotesUnderAssetsTabsData)
    AppExecutors.getInstance().diskIO().execute {

            agentDatabase.daoAccess()
                .insertNotesUnderAssetsData(state.listAllNotesUnderAssetsTabsData!!)
        state.listAllNotesUnderAssetsTabsData = null
        buildingRoomAssetsViewModel.sendAction(BuildingRoomAssetsViewModel.Action.CallHistoryVerificationUnderAssetsTabData)
    }
    return@onEach
}`


//Below is my retrofit builder code


` public static ApiInterfaceForAuth getApiInterface(Context context) {
        if (retrofitApi == null) {
            try {
                retrofitApi = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(CommonStrings.BASE_URL)
//                        .baseUrl(Config.AppMode.LIVE.getServerUrl())
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .client(httpClient(context).build())
                        .build();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return retrofitApi.create(ApiInterfaceForAuth.class);
    }`
```

Comment: Try with a post request. does it work ?

Comment: share your `ApiService` interface file and Retrofit code implementation

Comment: @Omkar i have added the retrofit code

Comment: not this, Retrofit.Builder() code with intercepter configuration

Comment: @Omkar here it is

Comment: share httpClient(context) and ApiInterfaceForAuth related code

Comment: API is working Fine . Problem is the size of api 142mb that's why execption is hittting . is there any way to insert this response in roomdb

Comment: yes I can see API is working fine on postman but you struggle to load that API in android device so you may need to disable Logging in OKhttpClient intercepter and also try to add notation `@Streaming` to GET type api notes